# Check SQL schema for reserved words and find suitable replacement

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, reserved-words

Wasted many hours troubleshooting my DB which included `maxValue` as a column name.  I've since discovered it was a reserved word.

I've used `type` and `timestamp` with both MySQL and MariaDB without issues, but I've learned my lesson, and will never do so again (MySQL shows both as being reserved, yet MariaDB only shows `timestamp` and even says its still okay to use).

1. Is there some sort of online tool which will check the schema using the SQL dump or create SQL for reserved words?
2. Is there any resource or strategy showing typical replacement words.  I suppose I can make them plural but doing so goes against my personnel standard.

Comment: Reserved words are well documented:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html.  Plurals help (and I use them for table names), but some reserved words such as `VALUES` and `READS` are plural.

Comment: Yes they are Gordon, but I have not found a tool to check or recommendations of replacement words.  Is asking for a tool off-topic here?  What about the question about replacements?

Comment: I would think that some GUI tools identify bad syntax.  However, tool recommendation is outside the scope of Stack Overflow.

Comment: this might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8339396/all-reserved-words-of-every-dbms

Comment: Not mysql workbench as far as I can tell.  Not even looking for recommendations but just whether they are available.  Maybe I should write one when I have time as I think it would be useful for others.

Comment: @EstebanP.  I've seen a couple of these, but they require user to enter 1 word at a time.  I've tried even dumping a few lines of SQL for each of the listed tools, but none worked.

Comment: Its not a good solution, but if you wrap reserved words in backticks they will be understood as column names i.e. `\`timestamp\``

Comment: @RiggsFolly  I feel back-ticks will be a band-aide which will get me in trouble down the line.

Comment: you could get all reserved words with: SELECT * FROM mysql.help_keyword - next step would be searching for those words in your code

Comment: Actually, it will be rather easy to create such a tool.  Would it be worthwhile to make it publicly available?  Something like `select * from information_schema.columns
where table_schema = 'your_db'
order by table_name,ordinal_position` along with Esteban's last comment query would do it.

Comment: Would be simpler to write a tool to be run before designing a database that simply echo's the line `Read the manual first`

Comment: @RiggsFolly  Which manual?  Maria DB has 233 reserved words plus 8 exceptions (which I think are reserved words that you can use). MySQL has 622 reserved words.  Really, one probably should not use any reserved words for any common DB to improve portability.  Sorry, I haven't memorized them yet, and didn't realize `maxValue` was one.  Have you?

Comment: NO! But its fairly obvious to guess i.e. does this sound like an SQL command or datatype? And I use the manual if I am in any way unsure. There is an old adage `measure twice, cut once`

Comment: SQL was invented decades ago, when "reserved words" were "accepted".  Perl and PHP chose to prefix all variables with $, thereby avoiding such.  PL/I insisted that no word is reserved, making a nightmare for implementers and readers -- This is valid:  `IF IF THEN THEN ELSE ELSE END;`  Words 2,4,6 are variables; the rest are syntax.

Answer (score 0):

For what it is worth, here is a tool...

Note that `mysql.help_keyword` is not being supported with MariaDB 10.2.7, and I had to hardcode the reserved words.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
openlog('API', LOG_NDELAY, LOG_LOCAL2);

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && !empty($_POST['database'])) {

    $db=parse_ini_file(__DIR__.'/../config.ini',true)['mysql'];
    $pdo=new PDO("mysql:host={$db['host']};dbname={$db['dbname']};charset={$db['charset']}",$db['username'],$db['password'],array(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES=>false,PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY=>true,PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE=>PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE=>PDO::FETCH_OBJ));

    $error=['tableHelper'=>[],'columnHelper'=>[],'tableMdbReserved'=>[],'columnMdbReserved'=>[],'tableMdbException'=>[],'columnMdbException'=>[]];
    $stmt=$pdo->query('SELECT name FROM mysql.help_keyword');
    $reserved=$stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
    $mdbReserved=['ACCESSIBLE','ADD','ALL','ALTER','ANALYZE','AND','AS','ASC','ASENSITIVE','BEFORE','BETWEEN','BIGINT','BINARY','BLOB','BOTH','BY','CALL','CASCADE','CASE','CHANGE','CHAR','CHARACTER','CHECK','COLLATE','COLUMN','CONDITION','CONSTRAINT','CONTINUE','CONVERT','CREATE','CROSS','CURRENT_DATE','CURRENT_TIME','CURRENT_TIMESTAMP','CURRENT_USER','CURSOR','DATABASE','DATABASES','DAY_HOUR','DAY_MICROSECOND','DAY_MINUTE','DAY_SECOND','DEC','DECIMAL','DECLARE','DEFAULT','DELAYED','DELETE','DESC','DESCRIBE','DETERMINISTIC','DISTINCT','DISTINCTROW','DIV','DOUBLE','DROP','DUAL','EACH','ELSE','ELSEIF','ENCLOSED','ESCAPED','EXISTS','EXIT','EXPLAIN','FALSE','FETCH','FLOAT','FLOAT4','FLOAT8','FOR','FORCE','FOREIGN','FROM','FULLTEXT','GENERAL','GRANT','GROUP','HAVING','HIGH_PRIORITY','HOUR_MICROSECOND','HOUR_MINUTE','HOUR_SECOND','IF','IGNORE','IGNORE_SERVER_IDS','IN','INDEX','INFILE','INNER','INOUT','INSENSITIVE','INSERT','INT','INT1','INT2','INT3','INT4','INT8','INTEGER','INTERVAL','INTO','IS','ITERATE','JOIN','KEY','KEYS','KILL','LEADING','LEAVE','LEFT','LIKE','LIMIT','LINEAR','LINES','LOAD','LOCALTIME','LOCALTIMESTAMP','LOCK','LONG','LONGBLOB','LONGTEXT','LOOP','LOW_PRIORITY','MASTER_HEARTBEAT_PERIOD','MASTER_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT','MATCH','MAXVALUE','MEDIUMBLOB','MEDIUMINT','MEDIUMTEXT','MIDDLEINT','MINUTE_MICROSECOND','MINUTE_SECOND','MOD','MODIFIES','NATURAL','NOT','NO_WRITE_TO_BINLOG','NULL','NUMERIC','ON','OPTIMIZE','OPTION','OPTIONALLY','OR','ORDER','OUT','OUTER','OUTFILE','PARTITION','PRECISION','PRIMARY','PROCEDURE','PURGE','RANGE','READ','READS','READ_WRITE','REAL','RECURSIVE','REFERENCES','REGEXP','RELEASE','RENAME','REPEAT','REPLACE','REQUIRE','RESIGNAL','RESTRICT','RETURN','REVOKE','RIGHT','RLIKE','ROWS','SCHEMA','SCHEMAS','SECOND_MICROSECOND','SELECT','SENSITIVE','SEPARATOR','SET','SHOW','SIGNAL','SLOW','SMALLINT','SPATIAL','SPECIFIC','SQL','SQLEXCEPTION','SQLSTATE','SQLWARNING','SQL_BIG_RESULT','SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS','SQL_SMALL_RESULT','SSL','STARTING','STRAIGHT_JOIN','TABLE','TERMINATED','THEN','TINYBLOB','TINYINT','TINYTEXT','TO','TRAILING','TRIGGER','TRUE','UNDO','UNION','UNIQUE','UNLOCK','UNSIGNED','UPDATE','USAGE','USE','USING','UTC_DATE','UTC_TIME','UTC_TIMESTAMP','VALUES','VARBINARY','VARCHAR','VARCHARACTER','VARYING','WHEN','WHERE','WHILE','WITH','WRITE','XOR','YEAR_MONTH','ZEROFILL'];
    $mdbExceptions=['ACTION','BIT','DATE','ENUM','NO','TEXT','TIME','TIMESTAMP'];

    $stmt=$pdo->prepare('SELECT UPPER(TABLE_NAME) tn, UPPER(COLUMN_NAME) cn from information_schema.columns WHERE table_schema = ?');
    $stmt->execute([$_POST['database']]);
    while($rs=$stmt->fetch()) {
        if(in_array($rs->tn,$reserved)) {
            $error['tableHelper'][]=$rs->tn;
        }
        if(in_array($rs->cn,$reserved) && !in_array($rs->cn,$error['columnHelper'])) {
            $error['columnHelper'][]=$rs->cn;
        }
        if(in_array($rs->tn,$mdbReserved)) {
            $error['tableMdbReserved'][]=$rs->tn;
        }
        if(in_array($rs->cn,$mdbReserved) && !in_array($rs->cn,$error['columnMdbReserved'])) {
            $error['columnMdbReserved'][]=$rs->cn;
        }
        if(in_array($rs->tn,$mdbExceptions)) {
            $error['tableMdbException'][]=$rs->tn;
        }
        if(in_array($rs->cn,$mdbExceptions) && !in_array($rs->cn,$error['columnMdbException'])) {
            $error['columnMdbException'][]=$rs->cn;
        }
    }
    echo('<pre>'.print_r($error,1).'</pre>');
}
else {
    echo <<<EOT
<form method="post">
  Database Name: <input type="text" name="database"><br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
EOT;
}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [tableHelper] => Array
        (
        )

    [columnHelper] => Array
        (
            [0] => TYPE
            [1] => NAME
            [2] => TIMESTAMP
            [3] => OFFSET
            [4] => VALUE
            [5] => STATUS
            [6] => PORT
        )

    [tableMdbReserved] => Array
        (
        )

    [columnMdbReserved] => Array
        (
            [0] => MAXVALUE
        )

    [tableMdbException] => Array
        (
        )

    [columnMdbException] => Array
        (
            [0] => TIMESTAMP
        )

)
```

Comment: After all this, `maxValue` doesn't show up!  Evidently, `mysql.help_keyword` isn't being kept up.